# Parse Hosting and Requests Per Second

Tags: express, parse-platform, request, requests-per-second

I have written a small website for a non-profit. The website handles about 500 visitors per day, the site is pretty simple. It uses [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) and serves up .ejs files that are updated weekly. It does not have any user/admin login functionality and it does not save any data. The most it does is make a couple separate requests to the Parse Core to fetch some images, URLs, and other text. It also has a few forms that submit data using Mandrill.

First off, does serving up an .ejs web page constitute as a request?

Second, and I am probably being overly cautious, but I want to be sure that I can host this website using Parse and maintain the Free pricing plan at 30/req per-second. Do you think I can?

Let me know if I can be more specific with my description of how the website is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same question. Parse.com team told me they are only counting API requests against the 30/req limit not hosted file requests. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense anyway as any web site request would trigger several more requests to images etc.